# How to avoid double counting in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

Table **X** with columns as Productid, Subproductid and Price.

Table **Y** with columns Productid, Subproductid and Weight.

Data is as follows:

**Table X:**

```
+-----------+--------------+-------+
| Productid | Subproductid | Price |
+-----------+--------------+-------+
| ProductA  | s1           |     4 |
| ProductA  | s1           |     6 |
| ProductA  | s2           |    12 |
| ProductA  | s2           |     8 |
| ProductB  | s1           |     3 |
| ProductB  | s1           |     2 |
| ProductB  | s2           |     6 |
| ProductA  | s2           |     5 |
+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

**Table Y:**

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+
| Productid | Subproductid | Weight |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
| ProductA  | s1           |      3 |
| ProductA  | s2           |      5 |
| ProductB  | s1           |      4 |
| ProductB  | s2           |      1 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
```

For each product, I use Weighted price SQL as:

```
Select X.Productid, sum(X.price * Y.weight)/sum(Y.weight)
    from X,Y
    where X.Productid = Y.Productid
    And X.SubProductid = Y.SubProductid
Group by X.productid
```

But by using above query, I am double counting Table Y instances.

I want output as follows

**For ProductA**:
Weighted price is (4*3 + 6*3  + 12*5 + 8*5)/(3+5) = 16.5

**For ProductB**:
Weighted price is (3*4 + 2*4 + 6*1 +  5*1)/(4+1) = 6.2

How do I write query to get above result without double counting Table Y rows?

Comment: Are you missing the `group by x.productID` clause ?

Comment: Edited the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use always explicit `join` syntax that could be easier to read and  write.

You would require to use `subquery` with `joins` to get total `weight`

```
select x.Productid, 
       (1.0 * sum(x.price * y.weight) / 
       (select sum(weight) from y where Productid = x.Productid)) as WeightedPrice         
from x 
inner join y on y.Productid = x.Productid and 
                y.SubProductid = x.SubProductid
group by x.Productid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally join a subquery which will select `sum()` from `Y`:

```
SELECT X.Productid,
       sum(X.Price * Y.Weight)/Y_s.Weight
       FROM X
            INNER JOIN Y
                       ON Y.Productid = X.Productid
                          AND Y.SubProductid = X.Subproductid
            INNER JOIN (SELECT Productid,
                               sum(Weight) Weight
                               FROM Y
                               GROUP BY Productid) Y_s
                       ON X.Productid = Y_s.Productid
       GROUP BY X.productid;
```

Given that there is a mistake in the OP and the last line of the example data for `X` should read

```
| ProductB  | s2           |     5 |
```

not

```
| ProductA  | s2           |     5 |
```

this gives

```
+----------+-------+
| ProductA | 16.25 |
| ProductB |  6.20 |
+----------+-------+
```

, exactly what you wanted (There is another error in the OP as (4*3 + 6*3 + 12*5 + 8*5)/(3+5) = 16.25 != 16.5.)

Comment: I revised the answer. Thanks to Mourad!

Comment: @user3376169: Not that I was aware of. The problem is, that one time the sum over only the values from `Y` is needed, for the divisor, and the other time the joined ones from `X`and `Y` for the expressions that make up the dividend. In general those are different sets, hence I suggest it's not possible without a subquery. But I could easily miss something here and someone else comes up with a subqueryless solution. And I'd be happy to see that.